# How long does a 3DS have when the light turns red?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, new-nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds-2dsxl

When the power indicator on a 3DS turns red, about how much time is remaining on its battery life? I am asking this for all types of 3DS.

Comment: Probably depends on several factors; Is 3d on, is WiFi on, which model do you have (3ds, 3dsXL, N3ds, N3dsXL.... 2ds)

Comment: Like @TrentHawkins said: how much *time* is left depends on too many factors to provide a good answer. However, if you ask for how much *charge* (in percent) is left, you could guess how much time is left, depending on how long you've been using it already.

Answer (score 1):

For standard 3DS: (I don't have all of the 3DS versions to tell you about them)

A few minutes, if you're actively using it.

Mine's lasting about 5-10 minutes until it starts blinking, depending on enabled features (3d, WiFi,..), current game, screen brightness, etc. 

Sleep mode should last longer (30 minutes?), but I haven't watched the battery die in sleep mode, yet.

Comment: If its in sleep mode and wifi is turned off it can last for up to a day in my experience.

Comment: @Riley Completely on red power? I find that hard to believe.

Comment: @Pyritie You can try it out yourself if you don't believe me.

Comment: The regular, original 3DS lasts a little more than 1 day in standby from 100% charge. The New 3DS XL lasts significantly longer. Did you mean the New 3DS?

Comment: The question is the battery lifetime after it turned red.

Comment: I edited the question due to some complications with types of 3DSs. I had forgotten that there was more than one when I posted the question.

Comment: This makes it somewhat complicated since there is no real way to tell you that other than collecting info from several sources or someone who has of them.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your model, charging, and usage methods.

My 3DS lasted about 10 minutes after hitting Red, and 2 after hitting Critical playing Mario Kart 7 - Not a power hungry game.

My New 3DS XL lasts between 25-30 minutes on Red, and 5 on Critical playing Xenoblade Chronicles 3D, while exploring, not in massive battles. It also has more internals it needs to power than the original 3DS-two extra cores, twice the RAM, Face tracking to name a few-yet lasts vastly longer than the 3DS does.

Both are either always or never on the charger, at 5 brightness, and no power saving.

The New 3DS XL not only has a physically larger battery than the 3DS XL, but also slightly more power storage space ((mAh)). Batteries were also improved from day-1 3DS systems to todays systems as well.

The 3DS non-XL version was a failure batterywise-Never leave your charger behind.

Answer (score 0):

It generally lasts around 15-30 minutes depending on whether WiFi, 3D, and other things are on. My 3DS died a few seconds ago, so I can confirm it.